# schedule a particular job on preferred node within a 2 node cluster using Quartz.Net

Tags: .net, triggers, cluster-computing, scheduler, quartz

I have 2 windows server running application  with Quartz.net 2.2.4 scheduler, which are configured to run in clustered environment. The jobs are randomly picked by any of the node based on crontrigger. Is there a way i can schedule a particular job so that it is run only by same node each time. 
The particular job once picked by a node should be picked by same node throughout the day.